# Getting the Bluetooth settings Connect & pair screen using intent?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-intent, settings

I want to navigate directly to the bluetooth settings Connect & pair screen on a button click now I can navigate till the wireless settings..

My code is as follows:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.WirelessSettings");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's pretty simple, try this:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

Comment: but here where we can pass over file path to send it ?

Comment: after apply lock task mode, this intent not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571606/cannot-startactivity-using-intent

Answer (score 3):

Use the follwoing:

```
    Intent settings_intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(settings_intent, 0);
```

This way you will open Bluetooth settings page and later return back to your activity that started the Intent.

Comment: tried this and doesn't seem to work. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006768/2293226) other answer suggests it is not possible because that intent [produces no output](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS)