# android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS crashes on Samsung

Tags: android, bluetooth, samsung-mobile

Anybody have any idea why

```
Intent pairIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(pairIntent, 0);
```

Crashes on all Samsung devices, but works fine on emulator, HTC, Sony, LG etc.

EDITED -----------------------------------

Turns out Samsung also requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are getting an `ActivityNotFoundException`?

Comment: Don't have a Samsung device to debug on, but Samsung users report "app closed unexpectedly" when this intent is initiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an app in production, you need to have *something* that will allow you to get crash logs. That could be the default stuff that you get from shipping through the Play Store, or an open source solution like ACRA, or any number of service providers.

With regards to your crash, there is no guarantee that this activity is available. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS):

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.

The "safeguard" could be wrapping your `startActivity()` call in an exception handler, watching for `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Also, please note that you use `startActivity()`, not `startActivityForResult()`, with this `Intent` action. Again, quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS):

> Output: Nothing.

This means that there is no result, and using `startActivityForResult()` is a waste of time.

Comment: okay, that seems to make sense. It's still in development but just have a few people doing my beta testing. Great that that info comes standard with shipping through the Play Store.

Comment: thought Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS would be pretty much standard on all devices.

Comment: @user3380200: The screen might be, but there is no requirement that any device manufacturer include an `<intent-filter>` to get there. And, of course, this is just one documented reason why your app may be crashing here -- without a stack trace, nobody can really know.